# Creating a POST request in Alamofire with parameters AND have multipart form data in the HTTPBody

Tags: swift, http, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, alamofire

I'm trying to do an image upload to Amazon S3 using a http POST request (not through their SDK).

Here is the beginning of the Alamofire call I'm making:

```
        Alamofire   .request(Router.UploadImage( friend_id, params, body ))
                    .responseString { response in
                        switch response.result {
                        case .Success(let value):
                            completionHandler(value, nil)
                        case .Failure(let error):
                            completionHandler(nil, error)
                        }
                    }
```

This leads to the Router (following the "CRUD & Authorization" example in the official docs) that looks like this:

```
enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {
    case UploadImage( String, [String: AnyObject], [String: AnyObject] )
    ...
    var method: Alamofire.Method {
        switch self {
        case .UploadImage:
            return .POST
        ...
        }
    }
    ...
    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .UploadImage:
            return ""
        ...
        }
    }
    ...
    var URLRequest: NSMutableURLRequest {
        switch self {
        case .UploadImage(_, _, let body):
            mutableURLRequest.HTTPBody = **MULTIPART FORM DATA HERE**
        ...
        }

        switch self {
        case .UploadImage(_, let parameters, _):
            return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.JSON.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
        }
    }
}
```

How will I be able to include the multipart form data?
Thanks!